# How to add custom date format validation for DateTime in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to add validation to my date property to my class in my c# class.

```
public class Item
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime RecDate { get; set; }
}
```

But `RecDate` property sholud only accept the format `"yyyyDDmm"`. For example `20211709`.

If type another format, it should return error when I validate the `Item` object.

How can I set the validation format?

Comment: I think you might need to introduce an other string property and annotate that with a [RegularExpressionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute). And you can use that as the `setter`, whereas the `RecDate` becomes a calculated property.

Comment: RecDate is a DateTime. A DateTime is a DateTime and has no specific string format. yyyyDDmm is just a string display format which you can use Parse, ParseExact, TryParse to parse it into a DateTime. You are describing ParseExact. You better use a control like DateTimePicker. ie: var myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20213101", "yyyyddMM",null);

Comment: How to do this is explained in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by registering a custom model binder for dates in your global.asax and specify the format you want to use there:

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(DateTime)] = 
       new DateAndTimeModelBinder() { CustomFormat = "yyyyDDmm" };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use extension methods to format it with an `IFormatProvider` or a `string`, and implement the formatting validation if you want.

Comment: That's an interesting clue, but it doesn't explain how to do it.  Extension methods are just syntactic sugar for static methods, so I don't really see how that pertains, other than convenience.

Comment: then you could create a private method to validate the datetime, somehow. that strongly depends on your needs, or why are you trying to constrain the formatting.